# IdentityServer4 with asp.net core 1.0.0 gives 401 status code

Tags: identityserver4, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have created a asp.net core 1.0.0 project for web api. After getting fresh access token I am trying to access our secure api but every time I am getting 401 status code.

My code is as below.

Config.cs

```
public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return new List<Client>
              {
                new Client
                      {
                        ClientId = "client-id-full-8AD6FC84-BA55-4766-8A73-77D2B72884BA",
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                        ClientSecrets =
                        {
                          new Secret("secret-2-E2ED1446-18DD-42BD-8F38-41C64FC3F8A1".Sha256())
                        },
                        AllowedScopes = {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Email,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                            "shipmentapi"
                        }
                      }
              };
        }
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            var migrationsAssembly = typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetName().Name;
            services.AddDbContext<ShipmentContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

            services.AddTransient<IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator, ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>()
                    .AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>()
                    .AddTransient<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();

            // configure identity server with in-memory stores, keys, clients and scopes
            services.AddIdentityServer()
              .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
              .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
              .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApiResources());              

            services.AddCors();

            services.AddMvc();            
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Trace);
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));

            app.UseCors(builder =>
                builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:62688")
                .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .WithHeaders("accept", "content-type", "origin", "Authorization")
                .WithExposedHeaders("Authorization")
                );

            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseIdentityServer(); //HERE WE ENABLE IDENTITY SERVER

            //add this configuration for the middleware needed to validate the tokens
            app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "http://localhost:59861",
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                ApiName = "shipmentapi",
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true
            });

            //add this line to show the ERROR STATUS CODES
            app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

            app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Postman 
[image]

However by changing AllowedGrantTypes from ResourceOwnerPassword to ClientCredentials I am able to access our secure api. So Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong as I am quite new in this technology.

Comment: Just a guess ... do you need to include "shipmentapi" in the list of scopes when you request the token?

Comment: @Peter You are right that was the problem.